# How to bypass a webapi proxy and upload directly to the blob service

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

My front end needs access to blobs from my Azure Blob Service.

I use a WebApi as a proxy between the WebApi and the Blob service in order to handle auth & business rules.

When my front end wants to download a blob, the WebApi performs a redirection with a [SAS Token.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/) This allows the front end to download the blob directly from the Blob Service, so that the data does not have to flow thru the WebApi, which saves me money.

**What is the equivalent of this for uploads? How do I allow the front end to push a blob directly to the blob service without pushing the bits thru the WebApi?** I'm hoping there is a SAS token + Redirect equivalent for uploads.

Note: I've considered pushing the SAS token down to the front end and having the client issue the REST calls directly to the blob service. However I would like to avoid this as possible since my front end is currently agnostic of the blob service (it only talks to the proxy webapi).
^Because of the above, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19935404/upload-largefile-to-azure-blob-using-javascript) does not work for me.

Comment: What kind of application is your front end? Is it a browser based application?

Comment: @GauravMantri, yes browser based. I was about to delete this question when I saw your excellent answer to a related one. However I don't think you upload directly from the front-end to the blob service in your example. It still flows thru the WebApi. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say that. It is entirely possible to upload files in blob storage directly from browser using JavaScript/AJAX. Please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19935404/upload-largefile-to-azure-blob-using-javascript/19935777#19935777. You just need to enable CORS on your blob storage account so that javascript from your web application can communicate with your blob storage account. HTH.

Comment: I was actually referring to your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257377/upload-to-azure-blob-storage-with-shared-access-key?rq=1. Yes, as I mentioned in my question, my front-end code is currently unaware of the blob service. It always goes thru the proxy. I'd like to keep it decoupled if possible. (Note that I'll always need a proxy since I have to do Auth in anycase)

Comment: What do you mean by `my front-end code is currently unaware of the blob service`? Do you mean with the same front-end you want your users to upload to different cloud providers? For example, a user could upload to Amazon S3 or Azure Blob Storage?

Comment: Potentially. Abstracting the storage specifics behind the proxy allows me to change it without having to update the front-end. That said, if what I'm asking is impossible to do, I'll be happy to move this logic into my front end. It was possible for "download" so I figured it may be possible for "upload" as well.

Comment: I see. I think you have to go with concrete implementation of storage API somewhere (either on the client side or at your API level). The plus side of putting it on client side is that your web application directly talks to storage bypassing your API layer completely which is also recommended from better performance point of view (you don't have to scale your API infrastructure to support more users). If the client side of your application is not in your control then you get the flexibility of rolling out new changes just by changing your API layer.

Comment: `It was possible for "download" so I figured it may be possible for "upload" as well` --> This works simply because you're passing the control to download the blob to the browser by providing it a URL. For Upload it is not that straightforward and you would need to write some code.